# Notification Area is broken on first login

Tags: windows-7, sccm, user-profile

All of the Windows 7 computers on our domain have a broken Notification Area the first time a user logs on to that machine.  There are gaps where icons should be, and clicking on a gap doesn't open anything (e.g. the network icon is missing, so users are unsure of how to connect to a wireless network).

If the user logs off and back on, it's fixed from then on for that user.  However we use Deep Freeze, so this bug a big problem for us.

The problem is vaguely related to [KB945011](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/945011).  That article describes a similar problem, but one that is persistent.  I tried loading the default user's registry hive and looking in there, but those keys don't exist there.  I did note that the first log on creates an `IconStreams` value significantly larger than any consecutive log on.

If it were just a problem with one image, I would just start a new image from scratch, but it's in different images, including ones captured with SCCM 2007 and SCCM 2012.  Does anyone else have this problem?  Is there a solution?

Comment: I have seen this before, but not often enough to care to figure it out. So you're not alone.

Comment: Check your group policy settings- a quick way is to build from your image but do not domain join and see if the issue still occurs.  If it does see if your imaging process is copying profiles.

Comment: Is it possible this is the result of a package that's being installed during the task sequence? If you just run the task sequence with the minimal (just lay down the wim), does it still happen? I'd start with just laying down the wim, and gradually add options and packages (or groups of options and packages, since this is a long process) until the problem appears again. If the problem rate is 100% of your computers then you can be certain it's either a problem with the .wim or a problem with something being set during the TS, if you're using different .wims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that it's in the default user's registry hive, just *not* the hive that everyone is familiar with.  There is another smaller hive in a deeper subdirectory called `UsrClass.dat`.  The same keys are in there.  We will be pushing this out to all of our computers, and modifying all of our WIM images:

```
reg load "HKU\temp" "%systemdrive%\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat"
reg delete "HKU\temp\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" /v "IconStreams" /f
reg delete "HKU\temp\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" /v "PastIconsStream" /f
reg unload "HKU\temp"
```